# How can I stop this HTML form opening a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a HTML form to send a message to HipChat, however, it keeps opening a new tab saying it's sent from HipChat when I click the submit button. How can I prevent that? I want it to stay on the same page, possibly with a JavaScript popup telling them it's sent, without a redirect.

Code:

```html
<html>
<body>

<form id="myForm" action="https://api.hipchat.com/v1/rooms/message" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="room_id" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="message_format" value="text">
  <input type="hidden" name="from" value="example">
  <input type="hidden" name="color" value="red">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="auth_token" value="example">

  What is your name?
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="myMessage">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
      var msgElement = document.getElementById("myMessage");
      var textToSend = '@example' + msgElement.value;
      msgElement.value = textToSend;
      alert("Alert");
      return true;
    }
  };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lookup [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: take a look to e.preventDefault();

Comment: Can you specify if you are using jquery? The question is tagged 'jquery' yet no reference to it in the code example.